# Eclipse Marketplace Client API existing / available?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I would like to use  the Eclipse Marketplace Client (MPC) API to develop a custom Marketplace client in my RCP application.
I am developing my application under Eclipse Kepler (Service Release 1 - Build id: 20130919-0819).
I found a pretty interesting guide on customizing MPC [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EPP/MPC/Developer_Guide).
 
I carefully followed the guide instructions, but the proposed solution did not work in my case (the internal error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet." is thrown). 
This guide is pretty old (2010) and I wonder if there is some other newer documentation available, or if some of you guys may provide me with some sort of newer information about it.
The questions I would like to be answered are the following:

- Is it possible to create a customized version of a Marketplace Client?
- Is there any API for that available?
- Is there any documentation providing hints in that direction?

Any contribution is appreciated.

Comment: `Workbench has not been created yet` means you have not initialized Eclipse fully. The MPC will be expecting to run in the full Eclipse RCP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your goals are. If you want to add your own catalog with your own plugins, it's possible and not that difficult. If you want to create your completly own MPC and replace the standard one with your, I think it'll be difficult.

I haven't found any extension points or open interfaces that indicate it is intended to be replaced or customized.

At one time I wanted to create or change the marketplace client so that it only showed a catalog of my choosing, but that turned out to be quite difficult. [See my SO question here with my findings.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17026774/change-which-marketplaces-are-available)

There is also a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710543/how-can-i-control-what-marketplaces-are-shown-in-the-eclipse-marketplace-in-my-r).